# How can I produce a synchronisable calendar for web and mobile devices (natively)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have built a web application in PHP using CodeIgniter.  The application is based heavily around a calendar that allows the user to add, edit and remove events to that calendar.

One of the major requirements for the system is to use the native calendar on iPhone and Android devices.  The user needs to be able to not only view, but add, edit and delete items from their calendar.  I can produce a vcal file that the user can then load into their calendar, but that is only one-way synchronisation.

Is there a way this can be achieved?  I've thought about Google Calendars, but having used the API before I know how limiting it can be, and I'm unsure of support.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Based on some short research you'll need to write a native iPhone app, or find an existing one that can export the calendar. It's easier on the Android see here: http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=151674

Comment: It seems it may be possible using CalDAV, but I've had no experience of this, and wouldn't know where to start

Comment: I don't know anything about it either. You're gonna have to read the docs. Maybe someone else has used it and did a writeup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the calendar server protocol (CalDav). Have a look at http://www.davical.org/ which implements that very fine.

Remember that it's a huge task because all clients have their little quirks that you need to support.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like a lot of work.  I'll probably just make a native app for Android and iPhone, and make a mobile-friendly website.